# How to change Image component color via Unity animation setCurve?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I don't have much experience in Animation. That's why I have a hard time even with simple things.

I'm planning to write a script to render the animations in my game. I found a script on the internet and started testing on it, but the problem is that I couldn't change the color of the Image component.

I searched for the solution on Google for hours but none of them worked. I would be very happy if you can help.

Comment: you add the image colour and set the colours at the keyframes like any other animation porperty